# Error propagation and p value

Tags: p-value, error-propagation

Say I have parameters $a(x$) and $b(x)$, with $N_a(x)$ and $N_b(x)$ experimental measurement counts, respectively. $x$ is an independent variable ($x_1, x_2, ...$). For each $a$ and $b$, I can calculate the statistical significance between $x_1$, $x_2$, etc.

Then I calculate $c(x) = f(<a>,<b>)$. Note that in general $N_a$ is not the same as $N_b$ and both vary with $x$. The means and error estimates of $c$ at $x_1, x_2, ...$ can be easily computed using standard error propagation. But how do I compute the statistical significance ($p$-value) between $c(x_1)$, $c(x_2)$, etc?